# Having trouble comparing two indexes in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I don't understand the logic here:

```
import tkinter
t = tkinter.Text()
print(t.compare('1.2', '<', '1.3'))
print(t.compare('1.2', '>', '1.3'))
print(t.compare('1.2', '==', '1.3'))
```

This outputs False, False, True.
I thought that you were supposed to be able to compare indexes with the compare function of the Text widget.  And indexes are strings as in 'line.char'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compare` is based on the text in the `Text` widget object.

Initially, text is empty. So any indexing will return empty string; they are compared equal.

Insert some strings into the text widget, then you will see difference:

```
>>> t.insert(0.0, 'asdf')
>>> print(t.compare('1.2', '==', '1.3'))  # Comparing 'd' with 'f'
False
>>> print(t.compare('1.2', '<', '1.3'))
True
>>> print(t.compare('1.2', '>', '1.3'))
False
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  I thought it was comparing the actual indices instead of the text there.